# Is there a topological characterisation of non-Archimedean local fields?

Tags: general-topology, commutative-algebra

A local field is a locally compact field with a non-discrete topology. They classify as:

1. Archimedean, Char=0 : The Real line, or the Complex plane
2. Non-Archimedean, Char=0: Finite extensions of the p-adic rationals
3. Non-Archimedean, Char=p: Laurent series over a finite field

This is shown by the natural absolute value built from field by using the Haar measure (which is unique) for the additive structure, that is $|a|:=\mu(aK)/\mu(K)$ for any set $K$ of finite measure. This is well-defined since scalar factors cancel.

Is there a topological characterisation of the Archimedean property here? The characterisation I've seen in [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_field) uses the ring structure:

> it is a field that is complete with respect to a discrete valuation and whose residue field is finite.

Comment: Can you update your email ID here so that I can contact because I need to contact you ?. I am research scholar of mathematics from India

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Archimedian local fields are connected, non-archimedian local fields are totally disconnected.